# how to set website caption right and below to name using bootstrap 3.3.7v

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add caption to my website, but I am not getting how to do this using bootstrap 3.3.7v.  This is the code I am using. When I use css for caption my nav bar is displaying under the logo, but I have them side to side. I need to display logo and website name side to side and caption under the website name and little right to the website name.

```
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

           <div class="nav-logo">
    <span> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="100" alt="logo" />
         </span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h2>MyWebsite</h2>
    <div class="caption text-left" >CaptionHere</div> 

  </div>


        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
 collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
 toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column 
 Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column 
 Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column 
 Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column 
 Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio 
 Item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
 toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
 toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="404.html">404</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.nav-logo,
.caption.text-left {
  color: #eee;
}

.logocaption {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data- target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <span> <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" height="100" alt="logo" />
   </span>
        <div class="logocaption"><h2>MyWebiste</h2>
        <div class="caption text-left">CaptionTextHere</div></div>
        <!-- Caption text should be little right and under to MyWebiste Name -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried as you suggest me, but it's not working I have given complete nav, when I change as you per your suggestion my menu displaying under the logo, website name and caption.

Comment: please see https://prnt.sc/g6akpg, I want to display it same as Lightshot logo in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align right, user `text-right`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- toggle="collapse" data- target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <span> <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" height="100" alt="logo" />
   </span>
        <h2>MyWebiste</h2>
        <div class="caption text-right">CaptionTextHere</div>
        <!-- Caption text should be little right and under to MyWebiste Name -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<style>
.nav-logo,
.caption {
  color: #eee
}
</style>
```

check here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsvvg68e/1/

Comment: I need to display under the website name little right but not right alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The text in caption tag will directly show written into div/span tag (just under site's name).
In other words : Caption tag is not actually visible to browser. have a look on screenshot attached.
[image]
You need to add some div tag, put class name in it and apply css property to align it little right. http://prntscr.com/g6akpg
like

```
.caption {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's displaying next to the website name, but I need to display under (I mean next line) the website name and little right to it.

Comment: please see Lightshot logo , name and caption. I am trying to achieve the same